# Moment central of a binary image

Tags: image-processing, probability-or-statistics, image

I am implementing the Hu set of invariant moments detailed here [Hu set of invariant moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment).

I implemented the moment Image like this:

```
 {i,j}={0,0}
        m00 = Total[
          Flatten[Table[
            x^i y^j ImageValue[imagetest, {x, y}], {x, 1, 800}, {y, 1, 600}]]]
    {i,j}={1,0}
        m10 = Total[
          Flatten[Table[
            x^i y^j  ImageValue[imagetest, {x, y}], {x, 1, 800}, {y, 1, 
             600}]]]
m10/m00=371.972
    {i,j}={0,1}
        m01 = Total[
          Flatten[Table[
            x^i y^j ImageValue[imagetest, {x, y}], {x, 1, 800}, {y, 1, 600}]]]
    m01/m00=472.923
```

I remark that the time computing is very high compared to

```
    {cx,cy}=Flatten[ComponentMeasurements[imagetest, "Centroid"][[All,2]]] 
    {cx,cy}={371.997, 473.198}
```

and the result is not the same.
How can I reduce the time computing ? thanks!
[image: Hu set of invariant moments]

Comment: With `id=ImageData@Binarize@<your image here>`, do `Total@Flatten@(Range[0, 799] # & /@ id)/Total@Flatten@id + .5`. Compare this with the `cx` you got from the `ComponentMeasurements` result. Then read [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html) *and* the [details section](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html) for `ComponentMeasurements`... should be clear.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple but efficient way to calculate the moments of an image:

First, a little preparation:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ4G5.png"];
pixels = ImageData[img];    
xArr = N[Range[Length[pixels\[Transpose]]]] - .5;
yArr = N[Reverse[Range[Length[pixels]]]] - .5;
```

Then you can calculate the *i/j th* moment using:

```
moment[i_, j_] := (yArr^j) . pixels . (xArr^i)
```

(If it's not clear what's happening here: Calculating a `vector . matrix . vector` product is exactly the same as calculating an image moment. You just multiply the i/jth element in the matrix with the ith element in the first vector and the jth element in the second vector, then sum everything up.)

Mathematica's `Dot` operator is *very* fast. On my PC, calculating the first 6x6 moments:

```
Table[moment[i, j], {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 5}]; // Timing
```

takes about 15ms. I didn't check the higher moments, but at least the centroid:

```
centroid = {moment[1, 0], moment[0, 1]}/moment[0, 0]
```

> {371.997, 473.198}

matches the centroid `ComponentMeasurements` returns exactly.

Also, if you have a nice function that calculates the Hu moments for a binary image in the end, it would be nice if you'd share it. Sound like a useful thing to have!